# MVC Models not successfully updated but can't find reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This has been driving me nuts.

I keep getting the following exception

System.InvalidOperationException: The model of type 'Models.Expense' was not successfully updated.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix, String[] includeProperties, String[] excludeProperties, IDictionary`2 valueProvider)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model)
   atMVC.Controllers.BaseExpenseController.Edit(String id, FormCollection collection) in C:\Projects\Expenses.MVC\Controllers\BaseExpenseController.cs:line 109

But I can't track down why it is not updating, nothing in the exception suggests why it has not updated.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you post the code, it's hard to track down without it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Catch the exception or call TryUpdateModel instead. TryUpdateModel won't throw an exception if it can't update your model, it will just return false. You'll find the error details in the ModelState as suggested by Craig.
In fact UpdateModel just calls TryUpdateModel and throws if it returns false.

Comment: It is not so smart to ignore error. It will chase you all the time till it get you :)

Comment: To Milan's point, it's "best" to handle false.  Something like if(!TryUpdateModel(model)) return View("Edit", model).  Assuming you have validation wired up in the UI, it will show the errors.

Answer (score 12):

Examine the controller.ModelState and look for entries with Errors > 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing any code, but every time I've seen an exception of that type, 99% of the time it's been database related. Not to say the root cause isn't somewhere in the code, but it's quite possible you're missing something and trying to pass invalid data to the database. Other issues to look for would be any relationship handling that needs to take place.

Answer (score 1):

I have had same issue, and problem was cause I'm using IValidatableObject interface in model which was in relation with one I updated. Real problem was in database, since validation yield that I have duplicated entries for unique column :)

The thing is. You should use UpdateModel or TryUpdateModel, the both methods updates ModelState.IsValid. Now, sometimes it may be hard to find what is causing an error. Look at debugger for ModelState.ErrorKeys and check whether there is an entry which shouldn't be there :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I generally check 3 things.

1. Do each of the models members
   have getters and setters
2. Am I fulfilling the requirements of
   the model.  ie:  Is all required
   data present and correct?
3. Am I violating a relationship somewhere? Do I need to have default values on nested objects?

If that still fails then i revert to;

```
class MyClass(FormCollection collection)
{
  string a = collection["MyField"];
```

which usually works.

Answer (score 0):

On the generated webform, check if you have a hidden field, possibly ID of some sort that can not be updated.